# jstack output different when using -F switch

Tags: java, jstack

I see that the output from `jstack -l <pid>` vs `jstack -F <pid>` is quite different (though essentially the same). My understanding is that the -F when you use the jdwp protocol to get the stack dump information (empirically noted from the beginning of the jstack output).

Output of regular jstack:

```
"Worker-265" #15722 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f12547d2000 nid=0x3890 in Object.wait() [0x00007f12e7bfc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.sleep(WorkerPool.java:188)
        - locked <0x00000000816c2b90> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.startJob(WorkerPool.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:52)
```

Output of jstack -F

```
Thread 29628: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.sleep(long) @bci=52, line=188 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.startJob(org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker) @bci=78, line=220 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run() @bci=318, line=52 (Compiled frame)
```

This causes problems for thread stack dump parsing utilities like http://spotify.github.io/threaddump-analyzer/ which expect the output in the standard format. Is there a way (either a switch or a utility) to transform the output from jstack -F to the regular jstack output? I am too lazy to write the rigorous regexes to transform the output and was checking around if someone has already done the hardwork. Thanks in advance!